# Moving Asp.Net Mvc default application dbcontext class to another folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am building an asp MVC website. I am using authentication for my site so I took the default authentication method from the default template. Im now fully confused between the identity application dbcontext class and my custom dbcontext class for my application. I have many questions regarding this..

1) Should I enable migration for each dbcontexts separately?

2) Can I point the database of both the context to a single database? (I have seen answers saying it can be done..)Is there any problems for that?

3)Can I move the `Identitymodel.cs` class from models folder to my custom folder named Databases where my another dbcontext resides? I saw the namespaces still remain dbcontext.models and not dbcontext.databases

Can someone answer me.. I have looked up all the questions related to this still can't clear my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

1)No

2)yes you can do this but is better that you implement it in one context.
 how can you do this? your answer is here: 
create a class name of `ApplicationDbcontext`:

**ApplicationDbcontext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() :
        base("Server=.;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;")
    {
    }

   public DbSet<Person> Peoples { get; set; }
   // add poco classes here
}
```

create your `custom` Identity POCOs:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>

public class Role : IdentityRole<Guid,UserRole>

public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>

public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>

public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
```

now you have one DbContext and can delete `IdentiyMode.cs`

execute this command: `Add-Migration init` and `Update-Database --verbose`

**you don't need other DbContext**

`IdentityContext` inheritance `DbContext`:

```
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, 
             TUserClaim> : DbContext
```

Comment: still i will have 2 contexts.. one i created by me for my model dbsets and one from IdentityDbContext.

Comment: you do not need your context just define `Dbset<T>` in `ApplicationDbContext.cs` and you can  delete `IdentiyModel.cs`

Comment: oops! i think u didnt get me.i have 2 contexts.. 1)  public class AstroEntities:DbContext for my models  2) public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>.. so i was asking if i can add it in same folder or same namespace

Comment: i understand that what you say. Won't you have one context?

Comment: I say you don't need `AstroEntities` you can use just one context.

Comment: but that contanis all my model dbsets.

Comment: can u explain how to merge in a bit more detail

Comment: just copy your dbsets and past in `ApplicationDbContex.cs` like(Peoples ) my answer. just do this.

Comment: DbContext and IdentityDbContext both looks different type of context classes. . Ho can this work if i add dbset to IdentityDbContext than DbContext. if i can use IdentityDbContext for both models and security tabls then whats the use of DbContext class?

Comment: `IdentityDbContext` inheritance  from `Dbcontext` [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613255(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: oh ok. let me try.

Comment: @abhijith if my answer is correct to do Accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So if you really need to have two DbContexts (I'm curious why) you have to enable migration for each dbcontexts seperately. And you have to specify a folder for each Configuration.cs file to be generated. Something like this:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ApplicationDbContext -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\ApplicationDbContext
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project SomeWebApplication.

PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName YourCustomDbContext -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\YourCustomDbContext
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project SomeWebApplication.
```

Your contexts may point to the same db (and they can have one common connection string) as long as they don't refer do the same table.

Yes you may move IdentityModel to another folder but you have to manually change namespaces. (Or get ReSharper and it does it automatically)

Comment: "So if you really need to have two DbContexts (I'm curious why) ".. Im not familiar with making a single dbcontext from 2 dbcontexts. as its a scaffolded one im afraid if that might throw errors.