# ASP.net Identity EF, move it to another Layer

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I used ASP.net Identy in others MVC project, when I enabled migration with code first EF, create the tables in the DB, and the login automatically works  perfect.

But this new project it's quite bigger, so I need extra layers, I 've created a Data layer and enabled-migrations(EF codeFirst) on that project.

My question is: Which files moves or what can I do, to get the login working with this new arquitecture? And what have i change in the Account controller, to keep it working?

I'm quite a newbie in EF, there are some concept that i don't know, but I think that it is very simple. Can it be resolve only adding the ApplicationUser's class to mi CursosDbContext?

This's my solution:

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG4Ph.png)

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631109/moving-asp-net-mvc-default-application-dbcontext-class-to-another-folder?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving Asp.Net Mvc default application dbcontext class to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631109/moving-asp-net-mvc-default-application-dbcontext-class-to-another-folder)

Comment: thanks it helps me